# PHP email form will not output fields

Tags: php, html, forms

I cannot get my scripts running to send a simple email Here is the HTML part. It works on my other forms that I have out on my server. However, it does not like this code one bit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="send.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">All attendees' names</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter all names here" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="Yes" value="yes" checked/> Yes, I plan on attending
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="no" value="No" /> No, I do not plan on attending
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">All attendees' names</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comments" placeholder="Comments" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">RSVP</button>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

and here is the PHP code.

```
<?php


$url = 'index.html';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$yes = $_POST['yes'];
$no = $_POST['no'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$to  = "blah@gmail.com";
$from = "blah@gmail.com";
$subject = "RSVP";

// message

$messagetext = '   <html><body>';
$messagetext .= '  '.$name.'';
$messagetext .= '  '.$yes.' '.$no.'';
$messagetext .= '  '.$comments.'';
$messagetext .= '  </body></html>'; 

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "From: $from" . "\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: $from" . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' .  phpversion();

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $messagetext, $headers);
//echo $message;

echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
?>
```

Am I missing something really simple?

Comment: For one thing, you don't have a form element with `name="name"`, or `yes`, or `no` or `comments`

Comment: POST variables don't rely on `id` but on `name` you only have the one that is named `name="optionsRadios"`

Comment: mail method is commented.

Comment: Do not send mail like this , use smtp authentication, use phpmailer to send mail. when you will host it on a server there would be great chances to get this mail in spam folder.

Comment: Made the suggestions and Radio buttons do not show a value when emailing. How can I get them to show some value so I know what the user selects?

Comment: check mail in spam/junk folder.

Comment: Change `$yes = $_POST['yes'];` to `$choice = $_POST['optionsRadios'];` and get rid of `$no = $_POST['no'];` then just echo the `$choice` variable where you want it to appear. PHP will take care of the rest, pulling the choice from the radio button that was selected, since they're both named the same. @tgbrunet

Comment: I take it that it's working for you now, great. *ciao*